# Correct usage of Decimal objects in this expression

Tags: python, python-3.x, decimal

I need to calculate the area of any regular polygon. I acquired this formula from a good ol' google:

```
(n * l**2) / (4 * math.tan((180/n) * (math.pi/180)))
```

No matter how I use `decimal.Decimal` with these values I can never get it to work as intended. `n` and `l` are given as floats.

Can someone apply decimal object to this please? When `n` is 4 and `l` is 2, it should return `4`, but currently it returns `4.00000000000000156234` (or something along those lines).

Comment: *"No matter how I use decimal.Decimal"*? How *do* you use `Decimal`?

Comment: @zvone Sorry, bad wording - I meant "No matter where I use decimal objects".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the precision for the decimal object. Pi is an infinite decimal number, so the precision won't be a whole number.

You can do

```
from decimal import *

getcontext().prec = 1
```

or add to the decimal object by rounding down.

```
>>> Decimal('7.325').quantize(Decimal('.01'), rounding=ROUND_DOWN)
Decimal('7.32')
```

[take from docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/decimal.html)

Comment: I really have to apologise for the wording of this question. I forgot to round pi in my attempts, so I will just use 3.14 instead of `math.pi` , it makes little difference for the program I am writing.